# Accidentally enabled read-only mode

Tags: emacs

I accidentally enabled some mode because of which whenever I open any files present in particular path, those get opened in read-only mode by default. So I have to explicitly disable the read-only mode.(M-x read-only-mode).

Any help/pointer much appreciated to disable this default behaviour

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you *accidentally* changed configuration of your Emacs, so it opens every file in read-only mode even after restart?

Comment: Are you sure that you have writing permissions for files in that particular directory?

Comment: Yes. I changed the configuration of emacs(but not in ~/.emacs or any other config file) which causing this weird behavior. Also I have write permission to the files

Comment: Configuration is stored in `.emacs` file anyway. When you change something, Emacs will write some commands into the file. Try open it and look for suspicious lines...

Comment: I removed the .emacs and entire ~/emacs.d and still file is opening in read-only mode. I get message "Buffer is read-only" when I tried to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can just do `C-x C-q` to effect `M-x read-only-mode` (just a shortcut).

Second, do you see this problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`?  If not, the problem comes from your init file.

Third, use `C-h m` to find out what modes the buffers are in and what those modes do.  If they all share a mode (major or minor mode), check the description of that mode to see if it sounds like it might be the cause.  Then check your init file (`~/.emacs`) and your `custom-file` (if you use one), to see what might be initiating that mode.

Alternatively for third, recursively bisect your init file by commenting out bigger and bigger blocks of it until you find the culprit code.  You can use `M-x comment-region` to comment the region and (with `C-u`) to uncomment the region.  Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8, etc.